# Update Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to build a data-access layer using Linq to Entities. I've run into a problem where I'd like to update an entire object, but I'm unsure as to how to go about this. So far, I have the following:

```
public static Character Update(Character character)
        {
            using (Entities entities = new Entities())
            {

                Character characterToUpdate = entities.Characters.Where(c => c.PK_CharacterID == character.PK_CharacterID).First();
                characterToUpdate = character;

                entities.SaveChanges();
                return character;
            }
        }
```

However, I realize that changing the "Character" object in this case just replaces the instance of the object. Is there any way to update the object without doing it on a property-by-property basis?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so. You could implement a copy method in Character class that will copy all properties to current instance. ***void Copy(Character other)***

Comment: Why not attach that `character` object to your context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this without using an automapping library is this...

```
entities.Entry(characterToUpdate).CurrentValues.SetValues(character);
```

This will replace all properties that aren't navigational properties.